# update Android studio stops flutter framework

Tags: android, flutter, dart

After I **updated my studio** flutter stops to run and error message appeared

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Script 'C:\src\flutter\packages\flutter_tools\gradle\flutter.gradle' line: 904

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:compileFlutterBuildDebug'.
> Process 'command 'C:\src\flutter\bin\flutter.bat'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 47s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
```

how to fix this issue.

stack trace
[image]

Comment: can u share the stacktrace?

Comment: yes sure picture updated

Comment: This is the same error as above. I said stacktrace.

Answer (score 0):

I also had this issue, please run

```
flutter doctor
```

Check all cases are dismissed.  If not solve those first. it should work then